# Ajax issue in post method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using Ajax in a registration form. And sending data through post method however I am able to see the details like password in the network tab.

[image]

Comment: A solution for the visible password would be to hash it client side. When the site supports https it is also "secure"

Comment: Not sure why this is an issue? The browser will of course have access to all of the data that you send back and forth from your server, thus it will be visible in the network tab. However, it does many things to ensure that arbitrary code cannot extract this information. As long as you are sending this information via https, the data will be secured in transport.

Comment: An `input` field of `type='password'` will do that in the network tab to obscure the input just as you see •••• in the form itself on the page. Do not be alarmed, its doing what its meant to do. The big question is, on the SERVER end, in the `$_POST['password']` var, are you getting the value you expect?